# Hardware for testing MPPT algorithms

Tags: solar-cell, mppt

I have been working on an MPPT algorithm and I simulated on MATLAB , now I wish to test it practically.Can anyone suggest hardware or programmable MPPT charge controllers to which I can apply my algorithm?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microchip Application note AN1521 presents MCU-based MPPT controller, as well as several different MPPT algorithms plus source code. I've built several copies of this controller, it works and scales well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into the Solar Explorer by TI. The board includes a solar panel emulator that would be well-suited to the testing that you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test is to use a standard lab power supply with adjustable voltage and current limit. As you adjust the voltage and current limit, your MPPT should always track at the peak current point of your power supply.

If your MPPT continually adjusts the current to find the peak power point, then you should see your lab supply drop in and out of current limit as the circuit cycles the Power point.

Typical Lab power supply can deliver 3A / 30V. To simulate a 200W panel, you would need a supply that can deliver 45V at 5A approx.

Comment: but I dont have any hardwarae to implement that algorithm, can  u suggest a charge controller to which I can program my algorithm?

Comment: @user3843425 Time to break out Altium.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I misunderstood your queston. I thought you were asking how to test the completed circuit.. :-)